# Is there a tool to generate many resource files (.resx) for many-page application automatically?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, resource-files

Our WebForm ASP.NET application contains about 60 of .aspx and .ascx files. Is there any tool to generate (for the first time) their local resource files?

I know how to use the built-in tool in Visual Studio (2019, Community Ed.) -- you switch the page to the design mode, and then Tools -- Generate Local Resources. I am also aware that it modifies the sources by inserting `meta:resourcekey`.

Is there a tool that can do that for all pages of the application at once?

Comment: Sorry to be OT, but why would you like to have local resource files? It's a PITA IMHO. We have that in one application and it really sucks when we want the customer have to provide us with translations e.g. Life is much easier with global resource files for me. BTW, we have custom-written tools to manage the files, to partially answer your question.